# ASP.NET Core MVC returning checked items from a form in a razor view to controller

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with a view that shows a list of delisted books (with isActive = false). In this view I have added a column of checkbox against each book . When the form is submitted I want to set all the checked books to become active (isActive = true).

This is the view I am working with :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcBooksList.Models.Book>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delisted Books";
}


@if (Model != null)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DelistedForm", "Book", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookName)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Publisher)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Enlist
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Publisher)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />    <input type = "button" value = "Cancel" onclick = "location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'" />

    }

}
else
{
    <h3>No Books currently delisted</h3>
}
```

So my question is: how do I process this data in my controller action. As in when I click submit, will the form return `IEnumerable` of Books with `IsActive` set to true to the action??

I am trying something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DelistedForm(IEnumerable<Book> fromDelist)
{
        foreach (var item in fromDelist)
        {
            if (item.IsActive == true) ;
            // enlist code here 
        }
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: So you want to pass a list of books which `IsActive` is true when you click submit?Or you want to get a entire list of books and then get a list of books which `IsActive` is true in action?Which one do you want?

Comment: @YiyiYou Initially all books will have IsActive to false.I wanted to pass the books which are checked(checkboxes ticked), if thats possible..

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to pass a list of books which `IsActive` is true.YOu can add hidden inputs to bind the data of `BookName,Author,Publisher`.And then change the name attribute of the inputs to correct format when checkbox is checked before form submitting.Here is a demo:

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult DelistedForm()
        {
            return View(new List<Book> { new Book {  Author="a1", BookName="b1", IsActive=false, Publisher="p1"}, 
                new Book { Author = "a2", BookName = "b2", IsActive = false, Publisher = "p2" }, 
                new Book { Author = "a3", BookName = "b3", IsActive = false, Publisher = "p3" } });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Book/DelistedForm")]
        public ActionResult DelistedForm(IEnumerable<Book> fromDelist)
        {
            foreach (var item in fromDelist)
            {
                if (item.IsActive == true) ;
                // enlist code here 
            }
            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }
```

View:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DelistedForm", "Book", FormMethod.Post,new { @id="myForm"}))
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookName)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Publisher)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Enlist
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookName)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.BookName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Author)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Publisher)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Publisher)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'" />

    }

}
else
{
    <h3>No Books currently delisted</h3>
}
```

js:

```
<script>
        $("#myForm").submit(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $("tbody tr").each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("#item_IsActive").prop("checked")) {
                    $(this).find("#item_BookName").attr("name", "fromDelist[" + count + "].BookName");
                    $(this).find("#item_Author").attr("name", "fromDelist[" + count + "].Author");
                    $(this).find("#item_Publisher").attr("name", "fromDelist[" + count + "].Publisher");
                    $(this).find("#item_IsActive").attr("name", "fromDelist[" + count + "].IsActive");
                    count++;
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

result:
[image]